# Is it possible to get data of related model inside current model in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm building the Laravel app which using recursive url constructing. And I want to know is it possible to access data of the hasone related model within model to return constructed url direct to the view without interacting by controller.\

```
public function link(){
    var_dump($this->category());
    $url = ['news'];
    $url[] = $this->category()->url;
    $url[] = $this->url;
    return implode('/',$url);
}
```

Simple code example like this return this one

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$url (View: /???/resources/views/common/news/full_preview.blade.php) (View: /???/resources/views/common/news/full_preview.blade.php) (View: /???/resources/views/common/news/full_preview.blade.php)
```

So is there any good way solve it by using just eloquent models, or it's only possible by using controllers and so on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't call `$this->category()` as a function. The function calls the relationship, not the related model.

To get the related model, remove the parenthesis.

```
$this->category->url
```

[Here's the docs for relationships in laravel.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: By the way I think in your case, the relationship shouldn't be `hasOne`. It should be `BelongsTo`, since `category` could have more than one of your item.

Comment: Yep just what I need. Such a stupid mistake:) Thank you!